# starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)

Tags: linux, bash, kernel, init

I'am building Root filesystem for the *Linux Kernel(6.2.11)*.

I want to compile the *GNU Bash Shell(4.1)* as the init program of the system. I built bash and installed it to the path `/bin/`, then linked `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash`.

But when I use the command `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel sysroot/boot/bzImage -hda boot.img -append "root=/dev/sda` to run the system, it displays the message :

> "Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)
> Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. ".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJzuG.png)

May I ask what caused the above problem and how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: May I suggest to post this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?